# What are the differences between member functions and member variables in terms of symbols?

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, symbols, symlink

I'm learning to use `__attribute__ ((visibility("default")))` for symbol export

```c
// a.cpp
class A
{
public:
     __attribute__ ((visibility("default"))) void func() {;};
     __attribute__ ((visibility("default"))) int cnt;
};
```

But I ran into the following problem

```sh
# g++ -c a.cpp 
a.cpp:5:50: warning: ‘visibility’ attribute ignored [-Wattributes]
      __attribute__ ((visibility("default"))) int cnt;
                                                  ^~~
```

What's the difference between a member function and a member variable?
Why can one export a symbol and the other cannot?

Comment: Which symbol do you expect from (non-static) `A::cnt`?

Comment: Unrelated question: are you compiling under root? It's generally highly discouraged.

Comment: *I'm learning to use ... for symbol export.*  That's not suitable for C++.  You'll create for your project some horribly difficult to diagnose bugs.  Unless your code is only exposing a C API, but given the examples that is not the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Member functions are really just ordinary functions with special signature to accomodate the hidden `this` argument. So you can attach visibility attributes to them like to other global functions.

On the contrary, member *variables* do not correspond to global entities - they are just symbolic names for offsets inside memory occupied by object of the class. So there is no point in attaching visibility to them.